# How to read a text file's data vertically or column wise

Tags: c#, winforms, vertical-alignment

How can we read a text file column by column.

Check my new code: I can read the data row-wise using **text.split (' ')**
But how can be the file read as column wise? Lets assume that a file contains number of rows and columns but I was able to read the data/value horizontally. The code you see that below that's what I could execute!
SEE THE CODE BELOW:-

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        string text = "";
        text = textBox1.Text;

        string[] arr = text.Split(' ');
        textBox2.Text = arr[5];
        textBox3.Text = arr[8];
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        string file_name = "c:\\Excel\\count.txt";
        string txtline = "";

        System.IO.StreamReader objreader;
        objreader = new System.IO.StreamReader(file_name);

        do
        {
            txtline = txtline + objreader.ReadLine() + "\r\n";
            txtline = txtline + objreader.ReadToEnd() + "";
            this.textBox1.Text = "subzihut";

        }
        while (objreader.Peek() != -1);
        textBox1.Text = txtline;
        objreader.Close();

        }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     textBox4.Text = textBox2.Text + " " + textBox3.Text;
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: First off you'll get more help if you actually show some effort on your part.  Secondly I would parse that file into a collection of a custom class that exposes the values in those columns to be used.  But you're not really giving enough detail to know if that is the best course.

Comment: There's no need for an image of a screenshot of a text file with three columns and four lines. [Markdown tables](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) aren't hard to create.

Answer (score 1):

A textfile contains a sequence of characters, delimited by newline characters and probably other characters which are used as delimiters (usually a comma or a semiciolon).

When you read a file you simply read this stream of characters. There are helper functions which read such a file line-by-line (using the newline character as a delimiter).

In plain .Net there are no methods which read column-by-column.

So you should:

1. read the file line by line
2. split each line into fields/columns using `string.Split()` at the separator character(s)
3. access only the columns of interest

Answer (score 1):

You can simply read the file line by line, splitt the lines and do whatever you want.

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(@"c:\yourfile.txt");
foreach(var line in lines)
{
    var values = line.Split(' ');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's true that sometimes you just don't know where to start.  Here are some pointers.

1. You'll have to read the whole file in, probably using something like a `StreamReader`.
2. You can parse the first row into column names.  Use `StreamReader.ReadLine()` to get the first line and then do some simple string parsing on it.
3. You'll want to create some kind of class/object to store and access your data.
4. Once you have column names, continue to parse the following lines into the proper arrays.

Some here's a rough idea

```
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReadeR("C:\\my\\file\\location\\text.csv"))
{
    string header = sr.ReadLine();
    List<string> HeaderColumns = new List<string>(header.split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntires));
    myModelClass.Header = HeaderColumns;
```

etc...

You might also consider making some kind of dictionary to access columns by header name and index.

Answer (score 0):

```
public string getColumnString(int columnNumber){

    string[] lines = System.IO.ReadAllLines(@"C:\inputfile.txt");
    string stringTobeDisplayed = string.Empty;

    foreach(string line in lines) {
        if(columnNumber == -1){ //when column number is sent as -1 then read full line
           stringTobeDisplayed +=  line +"\n"
        }
        else{  //else read only the column required
            string [] words = line.Split();
            stringTobeDisplayed += word[columnNumber] +"\n"
       }
    }

  return stringTobeDisplayed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you:

```
public static void ReadFile(string path)
    {
        List<string> Col1 = new List<string>();
        List<string> Col2 = new List<string>();
        List<string> Col3 = new List<string>();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            while (sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                string header = sr.ReadLine();
                var values = header.Split(' ');
                Col1.Add(values[0]);
                Col2.Add(values[1]);
                Col3.Add(values[2]);
            } 
        }
    }
```